# Multiples of 20 in java

Tags: java

I done a coding to get the output 20,40,60,80 and 100.

**Multiple.java:**

```
public class Multiple {

    static int n=20;
    static int m;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            m=n*i;
            System.out.println(m);
        }

}
}
```

**Output:**

```
20
40
60
80
100
```

I didn't have any issue in this coding.I got an output successfully.But loop running 5 times.Let me know is there any other way to get these output(20,40,60,80 and 100) in simplest way.

Comment: I think that this is one of the shortest possible way. Not unless if you are going to `System.out.println()` them.. LOL

Comment: run a loop 5 times is not a big deal.

Comment: You can post it on CodeGolf and see the results ;-)

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera yes you are right but `interviewer` asked me like that.Thats why I am posted questions like this.

Comment: Any implementation will not cheap than normal 5 indexed loop :)

Comment: The loop is not running nearly 5 times it is running exactly 5 times.

Of course there is an other way to achieve exactly this output: Hardcode it, otherwise your code is exactly the way to go.

Comment: The only thing I can say about this code is that you don't need the static variables. Simply do: `for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) System.out.println(i * 20);` As for the for-loop, this is ridiculous...

Comment: @WundwinBorn yes but interviewer asked me like that.Thats why I am posted questions like this.I didn't know how to do this in another way.But he was telling without hardcode, it is possible.

Comment: looping is the best way to do this!!!

Comment: From this question, I understood interviewer doesn't had enough knowledge to ask a questions like this to me.Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very interesting. if you know the output result (it's fixed), why don't you write them out directly:

```
System.out.println(20);
System.out.println(40);
System.out.println(60);
System.out.println(80);
System.out.println(100);`
```

oh i see, you think that's too long. Then probably you can use the below:

```
int a = 0;
while(a<100){ a += 20; System.out.println(a);}
```

Enjoy it!

Comment: change it as `static int a=0;`